# Including Javascript snippet that starts with $ in Nuxt page - returns this.$ is not a function

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I'm often having difficulty figuring out how to include Javascript snippets in individual components/pages with Nuxt.  In the code below, I am getting $ is undefined:

```
<script>
export default {
    created() {
        this.$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
                || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

I've also tried removed this. - that gives me $ is undefined.  Any help is appreciated - thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use jQuery in Nuxt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use a [jQuery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery) syntax request with the $ shortcut function, but jQuery is not included in Nuxt or Vue.

You can install it with npm:

```sh
$ npm install jquery
```

And use it in your component (without this):

```js
<script>
import $ from 'jquery';


export default {
    created() {
        $(...).click(...);
    }
}
```

---

Another way is to import jQuery as global (see [nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/#global-settings)) in your `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  head: {
    script: [
      {
        src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - I've tried both ways now that I know its JQuery, however - I am getting this error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=#]:not([href=#])

Comment: I fixed it - the script isnt working as intended (I'll investigate further) - however to fix the above error I had to escape the # sign like so:  'a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])'

Answer (score 0):

That is jQuery, you will need to include the jQuery minified script in your code for that to work